# Do we need WiFi Dongle to install Scratch on EV3

Tags: ev3, wi-fi, scratch

I was wondering if I can install Scratch program on EV3 brick without the wifi dongle.

Appreciate any insight here.

Comment: Welcome. Where are you getting Scratch for EV3 from? I'm not aware of Scratch running natively on the EV3.

Answer (score 1):

No. Bluetooth on the computer you are using is necessary but you don't need a wifi dongle for either your computer or the ev3. If you are using the EV3+Scratch extension on [scratchx.org](http://scratchx.org/#extensions), all you need is the scratch x [plugin](https://scratch.mit.edu/info/ext_download/) and a computer with Bluetooth (or a bluetooth dongle).

[Here](http://kaspesla.github.io/ev3_scratch/) is a good article about how to set everything up.